# SSRS - Format Output of Dataset for Input of Parameter

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, datetime, reporting-services

I have a dataset that is driven by a stored procedure requiring a parameter. The parameter is `DATETIME` but I am unable to present in that way in the report because DateTime's show as a calendar and I need a dropdown of values.

Alas, I have a dataset that drives the choices for the parameter called BaselineDate. The issue comes down to the way that SSRS formats the DateTime value for the parameter then passes as VARCHAR to the stored procedure. The VARCHAR value is in the wrong format.

**SSRS**

[image: Baseline Date]

**Expected Value**

```
2016-04-07 13:01:19.173
```

**Update**

Per @Marco Bong's suggestions I have converted the dataset that is driving the Parameter options to the proper format. Unfortunately, SSRS I passing the parameter value as null.

Below is what is a debug table I created. I am simply inserting the value of the parameter into this table. As you can see SSRS is passing null to the stored procedure as `NULL` which in theory should be impossible as the parameter is set to not allow nulls. Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: Let me understand what you are trying. You have a dataset that populates your parameter with datetime values but your parameter is text data type, right?

Comment: Do you have access to SP code? I am pretty sure if you convert datetime to varchar it will be appear as you need. SSRS implicitely converts and format datetime column to text in order to populate the parameter.

Comment: Also you can create table variable and populate it from your SP. `INSERT INTO @MyTableVariable
EXEC MyStoredProcedure`. Then from the table CONVERT the column to VARCHAR.

Comment: I could do that but the issue I have is at the SSRS level. I need the user to pick the Publish Date from a drop down then that value be used in the stored procedure.

Comment: ou can create an internal parameter to pass the value to the SP and use your visible parameter to let user select the value then convert it again to a datetime and assign its value to the internal parameter which you have to pass to the SP `=CDATE(Parameters!visibleBaseLineDate.Value)`

Answer (score 1):

```
select CONVERT(NVARCHAR,getdate(),21) as dtValue
//output will be ===> 2016-04-13 08:32:16.697
```

### [image]

**Update**

If you want to use that selected value in another dataset (which execute your store prod), you may need to do this:

[image]

Then you can use this @param1 in your query.

Either where something = @param or set @baselineDate = @param

Comment: this has moved me a step closer unfortunately it has just unveiled more bizarre behavior. Please see update.

Comment: @ExceptionLimeCat getdate() is just an example for my query, your baseline value should come from storeprod? then just convert it ==> CONVERT(NVARCHAR,baselineDate,21) as baselineDate

Comment: No you are spot on but that value in the dropdown in NOT being passed to the store proc. NULL is passed.. even though it is not allowed and I have a textbox being populated be the chosen value

Comment: you mean the dropdown selected value will trigger another dataset which will execute your store prod?

Comment: No like: Select value -> Click View Report but it passes null not selected value